# How to get the Units by day via API - App store connect

Tags: app-store-connect

Is it possible to get the data from Units download by day or installed via API ? but the problem is hard to find the resources of documentation of it.

this image below is the data I want to have.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3NDF.png

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is that in this report generated by the API, the "Units" column counts the downloads, the "in-app purchases", "re-downloads" or other things, and this causes a difference in the number of units seen in the review on the Apple Connect Store, as @CameronPorter mentioned. However, when reading the documentation, I couldn't find a way to get only the downloads (units without the in-app purchase). See explanations below:

[Explanation of the problem cited in the Apple documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNUs3.png)

Link for reference: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev5340bf481

Answer (score 0):

It has several steps to archieve. First you have to follow 2 links here:
Create keys: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api

Create and sign JWT Token
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests

These important keys to get is:

```
IssuerId
KeyId
VendorId
PrivateKey
```

If you are using Python, I would suggest using [PyJWT](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to sign it

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import jwt

def sign_appstore_token(issuer_id, key_id, generated_private_key):
    bin_private_key = generated_private_key.encode()
    current_unix = int(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp())
    token = jwt.encode({
            "iss": issuer_id,
            "iat": current_unix,
            "exp": current_unix + 1000, 
            "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1",
    }, key= bin_private_key, algorithm= 'ES256', headers= {
        "alg": "ES256",
        "kid": key_id,
        "typ": "JWT"
    })
    return token
```

From generated token, continue following this link
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports

To get the Units, reportType should be `SALES`. Also noticed that reportDate and frequency have to consistency each other, if you specify `filter[frequency] = YEARLY, then filter[reportDate] = 2021` or `filter[frequency] = MONTHLY, then filter[reportDate] = 2021-06`. For more details, please refer to the above link

Sample query here:

```
https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports?filter[frequency]=YEARLY&filter[reportDate]=2021&filter[reportSubType]=SUMMARY&filter[reportType]=SALES&filter[vendorNumber]=YOUR_VENDOR_ID
Headers: Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ABOVE_TOKEN
```

You will get binary response if it is success, represented for .gz file as well. Extract gz to get .txt schema deliminated by `\t`

Columns:

```
Provider    Provider Country    SKU Developer   Title   Version Product Type Identifier Units   Developer Proceeds  Begin Date  End Date    Customer Currency   Country Code    Currency of Proceeds    Apple Identifier    Customer Price  Promo Code  Parent Identifier   Subscription    Period  Category    CMB Device  Supported Platforms Proceeds Reason Preserved Pricing   Client  Order Type
```

Python script here returns file content as text, you can do your next step, pandas table, or to model, it is up to you

```
import requests
import gzip
def download_appstore_objects(token, vendor_id, frequency, reportDate):
    link = f'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports?filter[frequency]={frequency}&filter[reportDate]={reportDate}&filter[reportSubType]=SUMMARY&filter[reportType]=SALES&filter[vendorNumber]={vendor_id}'
    response = requests.get(link, headers= {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}' })
    file_content = gzip.decompress(response.content).decode('utf-8')
    return file_content
```

Comment: I find that the units returned by this report do not match the units shown from the app store connect website.

Comment: I do not double check the Units because I have no rights to access portal, but I think it could be suffered by delay, or not correct filter day/report day. As it is official documents so I have no doubt about the matching units. Could you please explore more? @CameronPorter